# SoundPool not playing sound (while MediaPlayer does)

Tags: android, audio, soundpool

I am trying to play a sound in an app. However, using SoundPool I am unable to do so. The code is really simple and I don't see where it can fail.

A similar code but using MediaPlayer does work, but I am interested in using SoundPool.

**SoundPool code:**

```
private void playSound2(){
    SoundPool sp = new SoundPool.Builder().build();
    int soundID = sp.load(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound, 1);
    sp.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

**Context:**

```
public void goButtonClick(View view){
    Button goButton = findViewById(id.button2);
    if (onGoing){
        goButton.setText("GO!");
    } else {
        goButton.setText("STOP");
        //playSound();   // MediaPlayer
        playSound2();    // SoundPool
    }
    onGoing = !onGoing;
}
```

**MediaPlayer version (works):**

```
private void playSound(){
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Comment: @morales97 What happens if you make `sp` a member variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Play sound using soundpool example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069955/play-sound-using-soundpool-example)

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I was missing to wait for the loading of the sound file into soundPool. The correct code is:

```
private void playSound2() {
    SoundPool sp = new SoundPool.Builder().build();
    int soundID = sp.load(MainActivity.this, raw.sound, 1);
    sp.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int soundID, int i1) {
            sp.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }
    });
}
```